# How to get QASM code from an Amazon Braket circuit in Python?

Tags: quantum-circuit, qasm, amazon-braket

As an example, consider the following `Circuit` defined by using the Python `amazon-braket-sdk`:

```
from braket.circuits import Circuit

bell = Circuit()
bell.h(0)
bell.cnot(0, 1)
```

How can I get the corresponding QASM code? If possible, I would like to do it directly, namely without going through any other intermediate library.

Comment: Not sure how to do this directly in braket but using the `braket_to_tk`function from the pytket-braket extension will give you a pytket `Circuit`. You can then convert the `Circuit` to qasm with the `circuit_to_qasm` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get OpenQASM output from Braket circuits by using the following code:

```
from braket.circuits import Circuit
from braket.circuits.serialization import IRType

bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(0, 1)
qasm_ir = bell.to_ir(IRType.OPENQASM)
print(qasm_ir.source)
```

You can read more about to_ir [here](https://amazon-braket-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_apidoc/braket.circuits.circuit.html#braket.circuits.circuit.Circuit.to_ir).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Braket does not have native support for converting circuits to OpenQASM 2. So besides implementing your own Python script, there's not currently a way to do this that does not involve going through an "intermediate" library.

As mentioned by @Callum in the comments, you could go through [pytket](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/index.html) + [pytket-braket](https://cqcl.github.io/pytket-braket/api/index.html):

```
from pytket.qasm import circuit_to_qasm_str
from pytket.extensions.braket import braket_to_tk

circuit = # Amazon Braket circuit
qasm_str = circuit_to_qasm_str(braket_to_tk(circuit))
```

You could also go through [qBraid](https://docs.qbraid.com/en/latest/sdk/overview.html):

```
from qbraid import circuit_wrapper

circuit = # Amazon Braket circuit
qasm_str = circuit_wrapper(circuit).transpile("qasm2")
```

Integrations through [mitiq](https://github.com/unitaryfund/mitiq), [amazon-braket-pennylane-plugin-python](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-pennylane-plugin-python/tree/main), or [qiskit-braket-provider](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider) could also be equally if not more efficient than direct qasm conversions depending on your use-case.

**Edit**: Was not considering OpenQASM 3 conversions, which are supported! See [answer above](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/32820/13991) :)